# Formatting SQL Source Code in SSMS

Tags: ssms

There are several source code formatters for SQL in SSMS.

I have tried a couple and found that are not configurable in terms of what formatting they do (e.g. indenting).

Does anyone know of one that is configurable in terms of how it formats the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) or [poorsql](http://poorsql.com/). They both have ssms plugins and are freeware.

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate's SQL Prompt is what I use and has several dozen different settings. It also has a better auto suggestion and code snippet engine than many others I've tried. Well worth the money in terms of time saved.

Comment: Thansk. That is one I shall check.